# Pumping lemma and CFG

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I am solving problem in pumping lemma for context-free languages. I want to ask a hint for the following problem

$$L=\big\{www:w\in\{a,b\}^*\big\}$$

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: If $p$ is the pumping length, try starting with the word $w=a^{p-1}ba^{p-1}ba^{p-1}b$.

Comment: ok, thanks, i will try

Comment: @nuraureum: This one’s actually fairly easy; I think that you can probably do it.

Comment: ok, I will solve it)